# Why there is inconsistence of a shell command in the same shell

Tags: shell, operating-systems

Like `sed`, there are shell command (or should I say it script language?) which don't behave in the same way in the same shell. Behavior of them seems to be different depending on OS (BSD or GNU) not on shell though they are shell command. I wonder at this. Could anyone give me a plain explanation ?

Comment: sed is not part of the shell.  Could you be more specific on which inconsistency is of concern?

Comment: I agree...  you're asking for a plain explanation, but the question isn't very plain.  Surely if you're using a different operating system, you're using a different executable for the shell.  There are various versions of sed that have been released, with different capabilities.  Some specific examples may help people to understand what information you're seeking.

Comment: I'm sorry not to question plainly for my poor English skill and poor knowledge about computer. I kept an example like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed) in my mind . Anyway It seems that I'd better learn more by myself.